# Removing the space when hiding the column

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using *JasperReports 4.5.0* to generate the reports. I am generating the reports in different formats like html, csv, pdf, xls, doc. In one of my report I have 6 columns say *col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6*. But based on the condition I want to hide the *col4*. For this I am using the ***printWhenExpression***. Now it is hiding the column based on the condition but the problem is the space occupied by that column is remaining same.

How can I remove this empty space in between the *col3* and *col5*?

The below code is for understanding how i am using it.

```
<staticText>
                <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="0" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{routeType}==Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Col4]]></text>
            </staticText>

<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="0" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{routeType}==Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{col4}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
```

This field will print only if the routeType value is false.Otherwise it should remove the column with empty space also.

Answer (score 2):

- You can use ***JasperReports API*** or ***DynamicJasper API***

[Here is](http://dynamicjasper.com/documentation-examples/getting-started/) the samples of using ***DynamicJasper API***

- You can use "fake" field (*textField*) for showing data of one column instead of showing two fields (two columns)

You can put another *textField* (which has the width of two *textFields*) under the both *textFields*. Using ***printWhenExpression*** property you can show two columns or one.

#### Here is the working sample.

Here is my report's design (in *iReport*):

[image]

My *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ..>
    <parameter name="hideStreetColumn" class="java.lang.Boolean">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[false]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, street, city FROM address]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="STREET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="139" y="13" width="279" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Sample of hiding column]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="189" y="33" width="211" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["To hide Street column: " + $P{hideStreetColumn}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="200" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{hideStreetColumn}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{hideStreetColumn}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STREET}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{hideStreetColumn}]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <box leftPadding="10">
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

To show all three columns we should set ***hideStreetColumn*** parameter to **false**. The result will be:

[image: All columns are visible]

To show only two columns (the Street column is hiding) we should set ***hideStreetColumn*** parameter to **true**. The result will be:

[image: The street column is hiding]

Comment: Hi,The Example you have given is fine.But here based on the condition you are displaying either one column or two columns.But in my case Based on the condition the column vl show or hidden.If it is hidden then i want to remove the empty space occupied by that column.

Comment: That exactly what I do in this sample. I'm removing column and shifting the other column

Comment: It can be six or twenty columns, never mind. The main idea is to use "fake" field (or several fields) and to use ***printWhenExpression*** property

Comment: I have done as you mentioned and getting the result.But if the report has more pages then from the second page onwards in the first row of every page it is showing the value of that particular field only and all the remaining fields are empty.It is looking not good.

Comment: Can you illustrate your words with help of screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

You can trick it with two detail bands. One detail band  B1 with 6 columns and the second band B2 with 5 columns. Then in the band properties print B1 when printWhenExpression is false and B2 when printWhenExpression is true.