# Limit columns per page

Tags: jasper-reports

Am working with *iReport 4.0.1*.

How can i limit columns per 1st page of table. From next page it should display remaining columns?

Can anyone provide me solution.

Is their any expression that implements above one?

Comment: Could you give some more information on what you want to accomplish? Do you want a fixed number of columns on the first page?

Comment: @user1831354 This posts can help you: [How do I hide a table column based on its content?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16700531/876298) & [Removing the space when hiding the column](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12121312/876298) & [jasper reports, hiding columns at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/116053/876298)

Comment: Refer these also: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/527248/restrict-number-lines-page-ireport

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/537135/number-rows-page

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/800395/how-display-15-records-page-jasper-report-using-list

http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/524831/restricting-no-rows-page