# Removing the extra space horizontally when hiding the textfield in jasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using JasperReports 5.6.0 to generate the reports. I am generating the reports in different formats like html, csv, pdf, xls, doc. In one of my report I have 5 TextField. I want to hide the TextField when it null.suppose textField2 is null then it hide and TextField3 Replace the position of TextField2. For this I am using the printWhenExpression. Now it is hiding the textField when it null but the problem is the space occupied by that textfield is remaining same.

How can I remove this empty space in textField when it null?

The below code is for understanding how i am using it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="RemoveSpace Ex" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d8585174-6b4e-4746-a5fe-2dfd5af32a61">
<parameter name="ABC" class="java.lang.Boolean">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[false]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select * from Student]]>
</queryString>
<field name="ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/> 
<field name="FIRSTNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="LASTNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="USERNAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="PASSWORD" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="PHONE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<title>
    <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="139" y="13" width="279" height="20" uuid="e1b06699-645f-4906-9066-f3cd1ed70d81"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Sample of hiding column]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="189" y="33" width="211" height="20" uuid="b619aa59-f5e6-465c-b303-4a5a5879e0f4"/>
            <box leftPadding="10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["To hide Street column: " + $P{ABC}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</title>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="500" height="20" uuid="15d3a067-378f-4ec5-a325-446142c18bea">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{ABC}]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <box leftPadding="10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FIRSTNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="4c77324f-e097-45ce-b2bb-5103f19467d4"/>
            <box leftPadding="10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="df0c1287-3495-4e82-a630-5ac574812956">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{ABC}]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <box leftPadding="10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LASTNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="f8393dbd-e99d-4aeb-b5ff-91810bd97d59">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{ABC}]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <box leftPadding="10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{FIRSTNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="300" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="f8393dbd-e99d-4aeb-b5ff-91810bd97d59">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{ABC}]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <box leftPadding="10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{USERNAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="400" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="f8393dbd-e99d-4aeb-b5ff-91810bd97d59">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{ABC}]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <box leftPadding="10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PASSWORD}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="500" y="0" width="100" height="20"    uuid="f8393dbd-e99d-4aeb-b5ff-91810bd97d59">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[!$P{ABC}]]>    </printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <box leftPadding="10"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PHONE}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I use How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports? method but the space can't remove...!!

Comment: I use "  How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports? "

Comment: i use  How to remove extra space between textfield in JasperReports? answer.it is perfect.but how we can it for horizontally..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing the space when hiding the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121312/removing-the-space-when-hiding-the-column)